# Making following select thread safe

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL in a stored procedure that is used to use a table as a queue:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AppRegistrations]
SET LastUsed = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP (1) Id 
            FROM [dbo].[AppRegistrations] 
            ORDER BY LastUsed)
```

I was informed in here that above was thread safe.

I also tried following:

```
declare @id int
declare @name as nvarchar(512)
declare @applicationId as nvarchar(512)
declare @applicationKey as nvarchar(512)

select top 1 
    @id = id,
    @name = name,
    @applicationId = [ApplicationId],
    @applicationKey = [ApplicationKey] 
from 
    [dbo].[AppRegistrations] with (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
order by 
    LastUsed 

Update [dbo].[AppRegistrations] 
set LastUsed = getdate() 
where id = @id

select 
    @id as Id, @name as Name, 
    @applicationId as ApplicationId, @applicationKey as ApplicationKey
```

We have around 50 jobs running concurrently. The table has 50 rows and the goal is that no job is using same app registration. Any suggestion to make one of the two SQL statements thread safe? Is it by doing a table lock or what is the correct approach?

Comment: Why not use a real queuing mechanism?  SQL Server support it:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: That could surely be a good option. Can you do it without emptying the table? It is not like a FIFO or LIFO but more like a "Give me the one who havent been used for the longest time".